# Accessing 'Summon Eidolon' as a Druid

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, druid, summoning, summoner

I'm currently playing as an Elemental Ally Druid, an archetyped class I'm enjoying considerably, in spite of the somewhat-nerfed Eidolons. I've been able to build each of them as a distinct character, with interesting personalities. One thing I'd like to be able to do, though, is summon one in a pinch, in case I don't have a full minute to enact the ritual, or have otherwise been unable to maintain continual company with one.

So far, the only idea I have toward accomplishing this is with a scroll or a wand of Summon Eidolon, and Use Magic Device. Are there any others beyond that? Is there a way to add it to my spell list?

And next, regarding exploitative caveats with access to such a spell, I am able to treat Elementals as Animals, including my Eidolons. In this case, it seems Augment Summoning, Versatile Summon Nature's Ally, and my Lesser Rod of Giant Summoning would all be viable augmentations to a casting of this spell if it were on my spell list (though not, if I surmise correctly, if it were from a scroll or wand).

Ultimately, I'm not looking for a way to game the system and summon a flaming munchkin. This is, more than anything, in the interest of character-driven, role-playing scenarios where such a spell would make sense to be.

Comment: You may attract better answers if you delete the last paragraph and/or add the "RAW" tag. The simplistic answer is "work with your DM to write a custom class/go on a vision quest/whatever else," but it sounds like you're looking for more than that. Even though "rules-as-written" means more than just rules, signaling that you want RAW answers may get a lot closer to what you want. Similarly, you may want to avoid pre-screening "munchkin-ey" answers. Different people have different thresholds, and you can always sandbag.

Comment: @fectin The [[tag:rules-as-written]] tag is not for signalling how to answer. Tags are only for categorising the problem content of a question post. (See the tag's description for usage notes.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yes, I picked a remarkably bad way to say that. Even so, I think he really is asking for a RAW answer, and I'm not sure how else to point him at it.

Comment: @fectin I don't see any invitations to hear homebrew or house rules, and it only references the official rules so far as I can tell, so it doesn't look like any special efforts need to be made to get a rules-based answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It's probably best for an [elemental ally](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/elemental-ally-druid-archetype/) [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/) who wants to cast [*summon eidolon*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-eidolon/) to stick with wands and scrolls

There are a handful of other ways for a [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/) with the archetype [elemental ally](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/elemental-ally-druid-archetype/) to access the spell [*summon eidolon*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-eidolon/) or a similar effect—for example, a druid could have a summoner cast the spell *summon eidolon* into a [*ring of spell storing*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-spell-storing/) or an [*ioun stone* (vibrant purple prism)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/vibrant-purple-prism-ioun-stone/) or a generous GM could allow an elemental ally druid to benefit from a [*robe of gates*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/robe-of-gates/)—, but these tend to be *more* resource intensive than a few ranks in the skill Use Magic Device, some trinkets that increase the druid's Use Magic Device skill modifier, and a wand, a staff, or scrolls of the spell *summon eidolon*. There just doesn't seem to be any printed way to put onto the druid spell list the spell *summon eidolon*.

I hesitate to suggest it because it meets with resistance and disdain from players and GMs—and also because it's heavily dependent upon GM generosity *and* subject to strict [GM oversight](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/magic/designingSpells.html#_spell-research)—, but in this case it seems like the way to go is with [Independent Research](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Research-and-Designing-Spells): "A divine spellcaster can also research a [new] spell independently, much as an arcane spellcaster can." That said, *this* GM wouldn't have a problem with an elemental ally druid researching an original spell that's simply a druidic version of *summon eidolon*, but ask yours.

(There are many ways to add spells to spell lists in [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e), with which *Pathfinder* claims it is fully compatible, but I suspect bringing in material from another game is beyond this question's scope.)

#### Adding effects to a summoned eidolon because of having used the spell *summon eidolon*

If a caster casts the spell *summon eidolon*, consensus appears to be that the resultant eidolon benefits from any effects that affect appropriate creatures brought forth by the caster's summon spell. That is, an elemental ally druid that possesses the feat [Augment Summoning](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/augment-summoning-final/) who casts the spell *summon eidolon* applies the feat's benefit to the summoned eidolon, and, similarly, the effect of the [*lesser rod of giant summoning*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/rod-of-giant-summoning/) can also be applied when casting *summon eidolon*. ([An eidolon summoned by the ritual instead of the spell can't benefit, though.](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2k75q?Round-2-Rules-Questions#22))

(This reader's original thought was that because the spell *summon eidolon* specifically summons the eidolon "as if you had summoned your eidolon normally, except that it only remains with you for the duration of this spell," that the eidolon would *not* benefit from more general effects like the feat and the *rod*, the spell's specificity overriding the general rules. But, as I could find absolutely *no one* taking this position, I won't take it either. I leave this remnant here as a *possible* but likely flawed reading because *this* reader had that notion and somebody else might, too.)

However, the feat [Versatile Summon Nature's Ally](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/versatile-summon-nature-s-ally/) can't affect an eidolon brought forth by the spell *summon eidolon*, the spell *summon eidolon* not creating an effect like the spell *summon nature's ally*.

Keep in mind, though, that the *Pathfinder Core Rulebook* FAQ includes [this exchange](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9n9y):

> ***Does using a potion, scroll, staff, or wand count as "casting a spell" for purposes of feats and special abilities like Augment Summoning, Spell Focus, an evoker's ability to do extra damage with evocation spells, bloodline abilities, and so on?***
>
> No. Unless they specifically state otherwise, feats and abilities that modify spells you cast only affect actual spellcasting, not using magic items that emulate spellcasting or work like spellcasting.

Thus, for example, when a *wand of summon eidolon* is used to create the effect of the *summon eidolon* spell, the wand's user's Augment Summoning feat does *not* apply. Whether the *her casting* language of the *lesser rod of giant summoning* applies to the effect of the *wand of summon eidolon* is a question for the GM.

Comment: I appreciate such a thorough answer. I'm pretty sure our DM would allow my character to research his own version of it and add it to his spell list, but I wanted to look for alternatives first. It seems I came to a lot of the same conclusions your answer laid out. While it makes sense to me for Versatile Summon to be applicable to anything Augment Summoning is, the RAW doesn't seem to line up 100%. I'll have to keep that in mind. Again, thank you for such a solid answer.

Comment: @Eiketsu You're welcome. I'm just disappointed I couldn't help more. I remain flabbergasted that in the entirety of the  massive-and-still-growing *Pathfinder* corpus there's just no way—archetype, feat, magic item, spell, trait, whatever—to simply plop a summoner spell onto the druid spell list. Here's hoping that, in time, another user will have an answer for you that can expand on this one.

Comment: With a bit of UMD a Page of Spell Knowledge can *almost* get it on your spell list.  It makes it so can cast the spell as if it was one of your spells known.  Unfortunately, while druids have the spontaneous casting class feature, they don't have 'spells known' so it's unclear what it means when you add a spell to that list while emulating it being on your spell list.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Yeah, but trying to use the *page* that way means the player's poking at the dark corners of the Use Magic Device skill when, instead, the PC—who already *has* the skill Use Magic Device, by the way—could just buy and use a *wand of summon eidolon*, and the GM wouldn't want to punch the player in the face after an hour-long Use Magic Device  argument. So, yeah, look at the question's last 'graph as to why I'm hesitant to go shadier than the totally obvious. I'll support your answer, though, if you want to go there.

Comment: Budgetary constraints also come into play in this particular adventure. We just hit level 8 and haven't earned a coin since we started, at 5. It's more story-driven than financial, and the DM would almost certainly let me talk him into a wand or scroll at some point, but it'd be more convenient for all parties involved if it were just something I was able to do.